# Get class of the element that's clicked (this?) and apply it to another element (target) while removing any classes on the target element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Found lots of info on adding class to the thing that's clicked but not how to apply to *another* thing. I have a list. Each list item has a unique class. When I click any list item, I'd like to get that class name and apply it to the  element AND also remove any class(es) that are on the  element. I'd like to do this without JQuery.

Here's my scaffold, I'm not sure where to start…

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="typeface-alegreya">
            Alegreya
        </li>
        <li class="typeface-alegreya-sans">
            Alegreya Sans
        </li>
        <li class="typeface-archivo">
            Archivo
        </li>
        <li class="typeface-archivo-narrow">
            Archivo Narrow
        </li>
    </ul>
    <main class="typeface-chivo">The density of texture in a written or typeset page is called its color. This has nothing to do with red or green ink; it refers only to the darkness or blackness of the letterforms in mass. Once the demands of legibilty and logical order are satisfied, eveness of color is the typographer's normal aim. And color depends on four things: the design of the type, the spacing between the letters, the spacing between the words, and the spacing between the lines. None is independent of the others.
    </main>

    <script>
        const fontList = document.querySelectorAll('li');
        const fontApply = document.querySelector('main');
        
        fontList.addEventListener("click", () => {

            // get class of clicked li
            // remove class from target (main)
            // apply class to target (main)

            dialogFonts.close();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `addEventListener()` is not a method that can be called on the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

You could consider using the [`forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to loop through each of the element objects returned from `querySelectorAll()`, and then call their `addEventListener()` methods individually.

With that out the way, for the main crux of your question. We can clear all classes from the `<main>` element by setting its [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property to an empty string:

```js
fontApply.className = "";
```

To copy the class from the `<li>` clicked on, first we should get a reference to the `<li>` clicked on in the event listener function. We can get this from the [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object that is passed to the function:

```js
li.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
```

One property on this object is the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property which:

> […] is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched.

We can glean the class from the object referenced from `event.target` and apply it to `fontApply` (the `<main>` element object reference):

```js
fontApply.classList.add(event.target.className);
```

Full example:

```js
const dialogFonts = { close: () => {} };

const fontList = document.querySelectorAll("li");
const fontApply = document.querySelector("main");

fontList.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    fontApply.className = "";
    fontApply.classList.add(event.target.className);

    dialogFonts.close();
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="typeface-alegreya">Alegreya</li>
      <li class="typeface-alegreya-sans">Alegreya Sans</li>
      <li class="typeface-archivo">Archivo</li>
      <li class="typeface-archivo-narrow">Archivo Narrow</li>
    </ul>
    <main class="typeface-chivo">
      The density of texture in a written or typeset page is called its color.
      This has nothing to do with red or green ink; it refers only to the
      darkness or blackness of the letterforms in mass. Once the demands of
      legibilty and logical order are satisfied, eveness of color is the
      typographer's normal aim. And color depends on four things: the design of
      the type, the spacing between the letters, the spacing between the words,
      and the spacing between the lines. None is independent of the others.
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! I did not know addEventListener() cannot be called on the the querySelectorAll() NodeList. My <li> structure is:


<li class="typeface-alegreya">
Hamburgevons
<h3>Alegreya</h3><span class="hide">Humanist serif</span>
</li>

It doesn't fire if I click right on the h3 even though it's a child of the <li>? I would also like to take the text value of the h3 and appy it to a text input and the value of the <span> and aply it to an h4 child of the text input.

Comment: The `click` event should fire for any clicks inside the `<li>`, but the `target` might vary. You could look at using `currentTarget` to consistently have a reference to the `<li>` clicked. You can then get the `<h3>` child and do DOM modifications as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear on what exactly you want to do.
If you want to get the clicked li you can use the event target and if you want to get the classname use elem.className(). To add a specific class and remove all others you can use elem.setAttribute('class','classname').

```
const main = document.querySelector('.typeface-chivo')
fontList.forEach((li)=>{li.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let ckickedLi = e.target    
    let className = e.target.className; // or let className = clickedLi.className
    clickedLi.setAttribute('class', 'theClassYouWant');
    main.classList.add('.className')
})
})
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you. This is instructive. The first answer solved it. Get class of clicked li and apply to main.